# How to lift up sub-component data from within custom component - e.target.value always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a signup page that toggles between two forms depending on bool value in `this.state`. If bool == true it shows a personal sign up form and if it == false it shows a business sign up form. Only one form can be visible at once (I have it working up to here). My confusion arises when trying to preserve the state of the signup forms regardless of the bool value. i.e. If you start filling out personal form and switch to business form, I don't want to lose those entries. I see the solution to this being store the form progress in the signup page's state.

I'm attempting to lift the state up from each *SignUpForm component and track them in the two child objects in `this.state`, `personalForm` & `businessForm`. However, whenever I enter text, for example, the first name field `TextInput` I receive an error stating:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'form.first')

So naturally I started placing `console.log` statements in the lifting up workflow and this is what is printed after I try to start entering data into the form:

```
Handling internal personal form change!
Lifting up:
undefined
Handling personal change in SignUp page
Existing personal form:
Object {
  "email": "",
  "first": "",
  "last": "",
}
Updating personal form to:
undefined
Completed update, new personal form:
Object {
   "email": "",
  "first": "",
  "last": "",
}
undefined
Rendering personal form!
undefined
Rendering personal form!
undefined
```

As you can see, the data I'm trying to lift up is `undefined`. I started messing around with which component has the `onChange` method in PersonalSignUpForm. Right now it's a prop of the root `View` component, which of course, is not working. I tried placing it in the actual `TextInput` itself and that still yielded the same undefined error.

So, in summary, I *assume* my state lifting is failing because my *SignUpForm components are more than a single component/complex and React can't deduce what `e.target.value` is. How do I change my lifting up code to properly capture all changes to `TextInput` and store them in SignUp.js's state?

**SignUp.js**

```
export default class SignUpScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._handlePersonalAccountPress = this._handlePersonalAccountPress.bind(this);
        this._handleBusinessAccountPress = this._handleBusinessAccountPress.bind(this);
        this._handlePersonalFormChange = this._handlePersonalFormChange.bind(this);
        this._handleBusinessFormChange = this._handleBusinessFormChange.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            personalAccount: true,

            personalForm: {
                first: '',
                last: '',
                email: ''
            },

            businessForm: {
                company: '',
                email: ''
            }
        };
    }

    _handlePersonalAccountPress() {
        this.setState({personalAccount: true})
    }

    _handleBusinessAccountPress() {
        this.setState({personalAccount: false})
    }

    _handlePersonalFormChange(newForm) {
        console.log('Handling personal change in SignUp page')
        console.log('Existing personal form:')
        console.log(this.state.personalForm)
        console.log('Updating personal form to:')
        console.log(newForm)
        this.setState({personalForm: newForm})
        console.log('Completed update, new personal form:')
        console.log(this.state.personalForm)
    }

   render(){

        if (this.state.personalAccount) 
        {
            console.log(this.state.personalForm)
            form = <PersonalSignUpForm
                        _onFormChange={this._handlePersonalFormChange}
                        form={this.state.personalForm}/>;
        } 
        else 
        {
            form = <BusinessSignUpForm
                        _onFormChange={this._handleBusinessFormChange}
                        form={this.state.businessForm}/>;          
        }
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
                <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
                <View>
                    <AccountTypeButton
                        text='Personal'
                        onAccountChange={this._handlePersonalAccountPress} 
                        selected={this.state.personalAccount}/>
                    <AccountTypeButton 
                        text='Business'
                        onAccountChange={this._handleBusinessAccountPress} 
                        selected={!this.state.personalAccount}/>
                </View>
                {form}
                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this._onCreateAccountPress()}>
                        <Text>Create Account</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
  }
```

**PersonalSignUpForm.js**

*BusinessSignUpForm.js is the same just different TextInput*

```
export default class PersonalSignUpForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange (e) {
        console.log('Handling internal personal form change!')
        console.log('Lifting up:')
        console.log(e.target.value)
        this.props._onFormChange(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        console.log('Rendering personal form!')
        console.log(this.props.form)
        const form = this.props.form

        return (
            <View style={styles.forms}
                onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <View style={styles.textInputBorder}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
                        value={form.first} 
                        editable
                        placeholder='first name'/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.textInputBorder}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
                        value={form.last} 
                        editable
                        placeholder='last name'/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.textInputBorder}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
                        value={form.email} 
                        editable
                        placeholder='email'
                        keyboardType='email-address'/>
                    </View>
                </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you have something like [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to demo whats going on.

Answer (score -1):

Yes lifting state up is best practice and honestly the only way to achieve clean data flow across component hierarchy. BUT, what i'm saying is your trying to modify the state of the parent component directly within the child component by referencing the value passed from props.

You should be trying to update the state of the parent component by values changed within the child component by passing down a function as a prop to the child and calling that fn as shown in the example below.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/clever-mirzakhani-8v4ly?fontsize=14

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Wait I thought the whole point of "lifting state up" in React is that the parent component is the single source of truth for the child components? Thus, the parent passes the data to its children and they re-render as they are updated.

Comment: I don't agree with *I  think passing references from the parent component down to a child component is an antipattern and should be avoided*

Comment: that was poorly worded on my part, i've edited the answer for you. i didn't mean lifting state was antipattern, i meant the way you're passing `this.state.form` down to a child component and trying to modify the value of parent state directly within the child component.

Comment: @ravibagul91 you are both right and that's not what i meant. poorly worded on my part lol.

Comment: @DanielPark I understand your code snippet provides an alternative solution (using `useState` and hooks) but I'm not sure how to translate that into the structure I've provided. Of course my structure could be completely wrong but thats why I'm asking haha!

Comment: Ah, okay well then let me write it using component syntax.